# Insert to web-page one instance of custom HTML element more than once

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

As example, I dynamically create instance of some custom HTML element.
After this, I twice use `document.body.appendChild()` and this work, but this should no be. What I may do for prevent this?

I put sample about this situation below in the text. `RandomParagraphSizePlaceholder` is simple web-component from some book. I use it only for illustration purposes.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/h6cxjae5/

P.S. I see, that is something wrong with web component, may be.

Comment: _“and this work, but this should no be. What I may do for prevent this?”_ — What? What is or is not working? Prevent what? You can’t append the same element twice into two different places. See [How to appendChild(element) many times. (The same element)](/q/36635392/4642212).

Comment: I know that *"You can’t append the same element twice into two different places"*, but something like this happened. You may see something like this in fiddle. What I do wrong?

Comment: @ScienceKitten your custom element is not appended twice. Check the output of your HTML.

Comment: Well, the `connectedCallback` runs twice; the `disconnectedCallback` also runs. You still have a single element.

Comment: Ok. But what I see on web-page?

Comment: @ScienceKitten Why not simply inspect the element with the inspector built into your browser?

Comment: *connectedCallback: Invoked each time the custom element is appended into a document-connected element. This will happen each time the node is moved, and may happen before the element's contents have been fully parsed.* [MDN - Using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks)

Comment: I see, this is only one element, but with two children instead of one child node.

Comment: Web component content is duplicated. May be, because it created in ```connectedCallback```.

Comment: Instead of linking to a JSFiddle, which you can delete any minute, it is better to use the [ < >] button in the Stack Overflow editor and create a running SO snippet.

Comment: Why I need delete JSFiddle? But thanks for advice about [<>].

Answer (score 0):

Only one instance of web component exists in web-page.
But web component content is duplicated. May be, because it created in `connectedCallback`. I dont very famimiliar with web component :(.

Comment: And please do not answer your own answer, unless it really is an answer. Please keep Stack Overflow tidy

Answer (score 0):

You get **two** instances, because your code:

```js
 this.appendChild(document.importNode(placeholder.content, true));
```

effectively makes a **copy** (importNode) and then appends *another* element.

`connectedCallback` (corretcly running twice) has (in this case) nothing to do with it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode